# Navigator not work in Firebase messaging callback method

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to navigate specific page when user click `fcm` notification. Problem is navigator not work on callback method.

- My device received push noti well.
- I added `FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK` on noti body. And there's no missing data.
- Callback method run well, but only `Navigator` and `showDialog` not work. So I guess problem is related with `context`.

```
// main.dart

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _fm = new FirebaseMessaging();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
  GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'Main Navigator');

  final routes = {
//    skip on question
  };

  fcmSetting(context) {
    _fm.configure(
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        pushTo(message);  // not work
      },
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onMessage $message');  // it run well
        onMessageSend(message);  // but it's not
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        pushTo(message); // not work
      },
    );
    _fm.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));

    _fm.getToken().then((token) {
      DBFactory.getInstance().insert('fcmToken', token);
    });
  }

  pushTo(message) {
    if (message['type'] == 'notice') {
      Navigator.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => NoticeDetailScreen(message['id'])));
    }
  }

  onMessageSend(message) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (bd) => new AlertDialog(
          title: LText('메세지 도착!'),
          content: LText('$message'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            LFlatButton(
                text: '확인', onPressed: () => Navigator.of(bd).pop()),
          ],
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    fcmSetting(context);
    return new MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      title: 'App title',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

I tried already `Navigator.of(navigat`Navigator.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).push(...)`orKey.currentContext).push(...)` or `Navigator.of(context).push(...)`. But not work.

How do I solve it?

Comment: Navigator is avail in `MaterialApp` - you hierarchy is wrong. Make `MaterialApp` root of all widgets(app).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move the code from the App file into a widget. I would say create a home page and perform the navigation in there, make the home page the child of your MaterialApp and register the callbacks in the home view.

I haven't figured out why the context there doesn't work, but I experienced the same thing recently and had to move navigation into a view deeper down the line.